# NEURON python Graph() is blank

Tags: python, biological-neural-network, neuron-simulator

When using python interface for NEURON, when I create a `g=h.Graph()` object in python, with `g.addvar(...)` to plot a variable, clicking Init & Run results in an empty Graph:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the Graph() object, also add it to the global graphList. It will then be updated during run():

```
g = h.Graph()
g.addvar(...)

h.graphList[0].append(g)

h.run()
```

[image]